# Different Behaviors of Numpy Stack

Tags: python, numpy

Maybe this question is basic. But it does confuse me and caused an error.

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [np.matrix([[0, 1]]), np.matrix([[0,1]])]
np.stack(list1)  # This gives matrix([[0, 1], [0, 1]]), which is expected

list2 = [np.matrix([[0.]]), np.matrix([[0.]])]
np.stack(list2)  # This gives matrix([[0., 0.]]). 
                 # But I thought this would output matrix([[0.], [0.]])
```

What does it have different behaviors?

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably should use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`.

Comment: It doesn't - in both cases the list of input matrices is stacked to form the rows of the output matrix.

Comment: @NilsWerner: the `np.matrix` type actually does have a different meaning - the operations are specialized for the 2D case (matrix multiplications and such)

Comment: `np.matrix` arrays are always 2d.  With `np.array` instead, the results are (2,1,2) and (2,1,1) in shape.  To join `np.matrix` objects use `np.concatenate` directly with the desired `axis`.  The various `stack` functions don't add anything, since the inputs and output are all 2d.

Comment: @rammelmueller I am aware, but [even the docs discourage their use](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) and with the new `@` operator there is no real need anymore anyways.

Comment: @NilsWerner fair enough. thanks for pointing that out, I was not aware.